# Peforming a collection of expensive tasks concurrently in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I have the following code which is made to process a lot of data, the `run_experiments` prepares the data needed, and the `run_strategy` function processes that data and keeps the result in its internal state which is saved in the `strategy` object.

The Dataset iterator which is used to generate the data is a generator with prefetching built into it, another thread is fetching the next set of data while the main thread keeps running the main program.

Many strategies operate on the same day, so I created a `run_strategy` function which attempts to run different strategies but on the same data.

I want to make this concurrent, using either asnycio, threading or multiprocessing.

I tried multiple ways:

1. I used concurrent.futures - ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor
2. Spawning many threading.Thread objects with target of `run_strategy`
3. I tried briefly with async/await but I wasn't sure how to do that

What would be the best way to do this task in the most minimal amount of time?

My code:

```py
from experiments import Experiments
from database import TickDatabase
from dataset import Dataset
from logger import create_logger
import time
from utils import prepare_day, run_day

logger = create_logger(__name__, stream=True)
db = TickDatabase()


def log(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        strategy = args[0]
        day = args[1]
        logger.debug('Processing: %s (%s) | %s', strategy.id, strategy.symbol,
                     day.index[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        res = f(*args)
        logger.debug('Finished processing %s | %s', strategy.id,
                     day.index[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        return res

    return wrapper


@log
def run_strategy(strategy, day, warmup):
    renko_day = prepare_day(strategy, day, warmup)
    run_day(strategy, renko_day)


def run_experiments(symbol):
    experiments = Experiments(symbol, shuffle=True)
    strategies = experiments.export(10, randomize=True)

    for day, warmup in Dataset(symbol):

        # Logs
        # ----------------
        t1 = time.time()
        # ----------------

        for strategy in strategies:
            run_strategy(strategy, day, warmup)

        # Logs
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------
        t2 = time.time()
        t = (t2 - t1)
        logger.debug('Time to process one day: %.2f seconds', t)

        logger.debug(
            'Balances: %s',
            ', '.join([str(round(s.oms.balance)) for s in strategies]))
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------

    trades = [strategy.oms.trades for strategy in strategies]

    return trades


def main():
    # symbols = db.get_all_symbols()
    symbols = ['AAPL']

    for symbol in symbols:
        run_experiments(symbol)

    # Collect results
    # Create summary
    # Save in human readable format


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After trying concurrent.futures I am getting many duplicate logs and it doesn't seem to be executing the code in an expected, efficient way.

I added this piece inside `run_experiments`:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
            executor.map(run_strategy, strategies,
                         [day for _ in range(len(strategies))],
                         [warmup for _ in range(len(strategies))])
```

The logs print the ID of the strategy, time started, time finished and how long it took for all of them to run before moving on to the next day.

It also prints when prefetching was made by the Dataset object and for which date.

```
Pretching: 2018-01-16
--------------------->

Pretching: 2018-01-17
--------------------->
2021-06-03 23:00:06,946: Processing: 526320f154374080b3980c9482cbaaf9 (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:06,948: Processing: df1c07965b514fe19b3a084091062bf2 (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:06,989: Processing: 3e30d26938054c7ab3ae84ae3e9dd38f (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:07,008: Processing: 80e8dc6d2a4944ecaf22b43d6ff246c2 (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:07,023: Processing: 658a17c5094b4da1ba9ba38a19208b0b (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:07,034: Processing: 17309d5191c7491b8f7d1f49a22d63a7 (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:07,039: Processing: 658a17c5094b4da1ba9ba38a19208b0b (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:07,137: Processing: 099b2990debd47c593460726592133b4 (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:07,162: Processing: 526320f154374080b3980c9482cbaaf9 (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:07,231: Processing: 099b2990debd47c593460726592133b4 (AAPL) | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:26,414: Finished processing 80e8dc6d2a4944ecaf22b43d6ff246c2 | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:32,938: Finished processing 17309d5191c7491b8f7d1f49a22d63a7 | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:33,496: Finished processing 3e30d26938054c7ab3ae84ae3e9dd38f | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:36,785: Finished processing 099b2990debd47c593460726592133b4 | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:00:38,331: Finished processing 099b2990debd47c593460726592133b4 | 2018-01-16

Pretching: 2018-01-18
--------------------->
2021-06-03 23:02:06,097: Finished processing 658a17c5094b4da1ba9ba38a19208b0b | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:02:06,364: Finished processing 658a17c5094b4da1ba9ba38a19208b0b | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:02:08,142: Finished processing df1c07965b514fe19b3a084091062bf2 | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:02:11,910: Finished processing 526320f154374080b3980c9482cbaaf9 | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:02:12,505: Finished processing 526320f154374080b3980c9482cbaaf9 | 2018-01-16
2021-06-03 23:02:12,505: Time to process one day: 125.56 seconds
2021-06-03 23:02:12,505: Balances: 9871, 9955, 10035, 10071, 10164, 10071, 10164, 9976, 9871, 9976

Pretching: 2018-01-19
--------------------->
2021-06-03 23:02:12,506: Processing: 526320f154374080b3980c9482cbaaf9 (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:12,506: Processing: df1c07965b514fe19b3a084091062bf2 (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:12,507: Processing: 3e30d26938054c7ab3ae84ae3e9dd38f (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:12,509: Processing: 80e8dc6d2a4944ecaf22b43d6ff246c2 (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:12,515: Processing: 658a17c5094b4da1ba9ba38a19208b0b (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:12,544: Processing: 17309d5191c7491b8f7d1f49a22d63a7 (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:12,784: Processing: 658a17c5094b4da1ba9ba38a19208b0b (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:12,792: Processing: 099b2990debd47c593460726592133b4 (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:12,963: Processing: 526320f154374080b3980c9482cbaaf9 (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:13,288: Processing: 099b2990debd47c593460726592133b4 (AAPL) | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:34,574: Finished processing 80e8dc6d2a4944ecaf22b43d6ff246c2 | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:40,029: Finished processing 17309d5191c7491b8f7d1f49a22d63a7 | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:40,195: Finished processing 099b2990debd47c593460726592133b4 | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:40,339: Finished processing 3e30d26938054c7ab3ae84ae3e9dd38f | 2018-01-17
2021-06-03 23:02:41,286: Finished processing 099b2990debd47c593460726592133b4 | 2018-01-17
```

Comment: If your strategies are CPU-bound (require a lot of computations at CPU), the only way to achieve speed up is multiprocessing. But if what you're trying to do is IO-bound (a lot of time spent waiting for some IO operation like DB waiting, requests), then you can use either asyncio or multithreading

Comment: I have 1 task which is I/O bound, to bring data to from a database into scope - and the processing of this data is CPU bound, can I combine these libraries to work in conjunction? I mean bring data using asyncio and process it with multiprocessing?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that